# Generate CFG using CFL Language

Tags: automata

I have the following exercise  **(L={a^nb^ma^n|n,m>=1})**
I solved similar questions, but I got stuck on that.

Comment: HINT: Design the grammar to generate the $a$s first and then switch over to generating $b$s. It can be done with just four productions using just two non-terminal symbols.

Comment: Thank you for your help,i get it

Comment: Excellent! You’re welcome.